# Disable displayName option for styled components in next-config.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, babeljs, styled-components

is it possible to disable the `displayName` option for styled-components in the `next-config.js`? I know it's possible to disable by using a custom `.babelrc`, but i don't want to disable the **next.js SWC**, and if i create a custom `.babelrc` the SWC will be disabled.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I'm using Next/SWC, and I can't get it to use `displayName`!    I tried: `compiler: { styledComponents: { displayName: isDev, ssr: true } },` in `next.config.js`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```js
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: {
      displayName: true,
      ssr: true,
    },
```

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#supported-features